# Running ibus with i3 on Ubuntu with multiple users

Tags: ubuntu, tty, i3, gdm, ibus

I have Ubuntu 18.04 running and I installed i3 as my display manager. In this Ubuntu version, it is nevertheless the default to have a GDM login screen. If I login into any account, Ubuntu starts that display manager in another TTY. So the login GDM runs on TTY(0) and my first logged-in i3 runs on TTY(1) and the second logged-in i3 (different user) runs on TTY(2) etc. etc. Also to mention, that I have among my users one user who actually uses Gnome as display manager.

Actually I like that behaviour, because I can switch between users simply by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> for the first user, <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> for the second user and <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> for the login screen. Pretty convenient in my opinion.

The problem is, that I have not yet ever successfully ran ibus on any of those i3 instances with this setup. But the preferred behaviour would of course be that I had one ibus instance per TTY (=per user) so I could use the ibus settings of that specific user when logged in.

But in reallity it looks like this: There is always 1 instance of `ibus-daemon` ran by the user `gdm` (seems to be Ubuntu default, because I didn't touch any of that) and if I start my own, second, `ibus-daemon`, then my keyboard input suddenly stops working entirely. My guess is, that only one of the `ibus-daemon` instances can connect to the keyboard input and so my instance doesn't get any input. Oh, and that `ibus-daemon` instance of `gdm` is not killable (it will restart within milliseconds).

So… any ideas how I could get ibus and gdm to obey my will?

Answer (score 0):

Seems I've been wrong all along. Starting the `ibus-daemon` in the second instance never was the problem. The problem was that I had missed the `--xim` parameter...